# groovy のクロージャにおける、名前の解決がわからない(delegateを指定した場合の owner の挙動について)

Tags: groovy

Groovy を触り始めているものです。自分は、

1. クロージャは `delegate` を設定することで、その `delegate` に対しても名前の検索を行うようになる
2. クロージャは、その他に`owner` と `this` を持つ。`owner`は、そのクロージャが定義された「クロージャないしクラス」を指し示す
3. クロージャは、`resolveStrategy` を `Clousure.DELEGATE_ONLY`に設定することで、`owner`への探索を抑制することができる

と理解しているのですが、次のコードを実行すると、自分の期待とは違う挙動をしています。

```
class MyClass {
    def outerClosure = {
        def str = "outer"
        def nestedClosure = {
            println "delegate: ${delegate.class.name}"
            println "owner: ${owner.class.name}"
            println "this: ${this.class.name}"
            println "resolveStrategy: ${resolveStrategy}"
            println "Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY: ${Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY}"
            println(str)
        }
        nestedClosure
    }
}

class Hoge {
    def str = "hoge"
}

myObj = new MyClass()
hoge = new Hoge()
def nestedClosure = myObj.outerClosure()
nestedClosure.delegate = hoge
nestedClosure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY

nestedClosure()
```

出力:

```
delegate: Hoge
owner: MyClass$_closure1
this: MyClass
resolveStrategy: 3
Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY: 3
outer
```

というのも、 `DELEGATE_ONLY`にもかかわらず、`owner`のスコープを探して `outer`の`str`を見つけてきている様子なのですが、これは一体どうしてなのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`outerClosure()`を評価した時点で`outerClosure`のローカル変数の`str`が`nestedClosure` にキャプチャされるので、`delegate`に設定した`Hoge`を探索する以前に`str`が`outerClosure`由来の変数として解決できている、ということじゃないでしょうか。

`DELEGATE_ONLY`の効果を確かめたい場合は次のようにすると良いと思います。

```
class MyClass {
    // こっちに宣言しておくとDELEGATE_ONLYの効果がわかる
    def str = "myClassField"

    def outerClosure = {
        // ここに変数宣言してしまうとnestedClosureにキャプチャされてしまう。
        // delegateを探索する以前にこっちが見つかってしまう。
        //def str = "outer"

        def nestedClosure = {
            println "delegate: ${delegate.class.name}"
            println "owner: ${owner.class.name}"
            println "this: ${this.class.name}"
            println "resolveStrategy: ${resolveStrategy}"
            println "Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY: ${resolveStrategy == Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY}"
            return str
        }
        nestedClosure
    }
}

class Hoge {
    def str = "hoge"
}

def myObj = new MyClass()
def nestedClosure = myObj.outerClosure()
nestedClosure.delegate = new Hoge()

assert nestedClosure() == "myClassField"

nestedClosure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY

assert nestedClosure() == "hoge"
```

Comment: 1. メソッド内クロージャは、java でいうメソッド内クラスのように、変数をキャプチャできる
2. プロパティ(?) の owner の探索は、再帰的に行われる。

と理解しました。

Comment: 細かいですが「メソッド内」かどうかに関わらず、クロージャはレキシカルスコープを保持します。あとJavaの場合はfinalな変数しか無名内部クラス内で参照できませんが、Groovyのクロージャでは非final変数へも普通に参照できます。
(参考: http://uehaj.hatenablog.com/entry/20120222/1329925355)